# Duplicate key error index while insert record in mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, threadpoolexecutor

I've been getting the following error while use thread pool to save the OperateLog:

```
E11000 duplicate key error collection: ooomap.operate_log index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5e7fec87e28361433481a75b') }
```

Here is my sample code snippet:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++) {
            logger.info("start save operateLog "+ JSON.toJSONString(operateLog));
            this.operateLogService.createOperateLog(operateLog);
            logger.info("save operateLog success ");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("save operateLog error",e);
    }
}
```

Any help/suggestion for this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 0):

use `synchronized block while persisting in MongoDB`.
Or please share `Document pojo` of operateLog.

Hope this will work!